# Integrate Google Maps Into a current Rails Application

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-maps

Rails newbie here. I'm working on a project and I need to integrate google maps into a current rails application. I have the google maps javascript file working properly. My issue comes in when trying to integrate it with the current rails application. I have the html.erb file setup to reference the respective google maps js file, yet every time the page loads, I get an error in the console saying

"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"

in regards to the corresponding js file. Yet when I copy the javascript code into the html.erb file, google maps just loads fine. Any ideas on what I'm missing to have this setup working properly, I have been losing my mind over this for the past 24 hours and would greatly appreciate any help I can get. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Adding the code and errors below.

Here is the core of the google maps js with angular, I have commented out everything except loading the core google maps below

```
var My_Map = angular.module('My_Map' , []);

My_Map.directive("myMaps", function() {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<div></div>',
    replace: true,
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(34.0, -118.4),
            zoom: 12,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(attrs.id),
            mapOptions);
    }
};
});
```

Here is the html erb code chunk

```
<html ng-app="My_Map">

<head>

<%= javascript_include_tag "dispatcher_script", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>

<title>
    Google Maps
</title>

<style>

    #map-canvas{
        height:750px;
        width:1400px;
        border:2px solid red;
    }

</style>

</head>

<body>

<my-maps id="map-canvas"></my-maps>

<script type="text/javascript"
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=KEYHERE">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript"
            src="/app/assets/javascripts/angular-animate.min.js.map">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript"
        src = "/app/assets/javascripts/app/map_app.js">
</script>
```

And the console errors, stackoverflow wont let me post images, but its basically the following

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined dispatcher_script.js:1646
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)      https://NAME.herokuapp.com/app/assets/javascripts/app/map_app.js
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) https://NAME.herokuapp.com/app/assets/javascripts/angular-animate.min.js.map
```

Also, the file structure is rails compliant, have the js file placed in
    app/assets/javascripts/app 
and the html erb file is in 
    app/views/dispatchers

Comment: Did you follow this guide about how to organise, name and link asset files in Rails: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html ?

Comment: Show us the problematic code, where you've added the JS files, the full error from the console, etc...  This will greatly help your odds of getting good suggestions!

Comment: I believe I have, I read over the documentation, and I seem to have done the steps as outlined ...